# How to get the field value of current item language in Sitecore

Tags: multilingual, custom-field

I have created a custom Sitecore field from `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.NameLookupValue`.
But even after changing the language of the item where the custom field is added, context language, as well as the item language, is always coming as `en`.

So I am not able to get the value of the item field in other languages. `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(this.ItemID)` is always giving values of `en` language
I have tried with `httpcontext.current.request["sclanguage"]`. But it is always giving the previous language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LanguageSwitcher` to change the language:

e.g.

```
using (new LanguageSwitcher("OTHER LANGUAGE CODE"))
{
    var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(this.ItemID);
    var field = item.Fields["FieldName"];
}
```

Getting the field value without a language switcher will always use the current context language. If the context language is `en` - it will get the `en` language version.

Make sure that in your data template you have not ticked `Unversioned` or `Shared`

Comment: I tried this as well But how to get the field language in code while changing the item language

Comment: Your field would be getting rendered on a page present within a Sitecore site. You should be looking at Context Language in code, something like this Sitecore.Context.Language, to get the language in code.

Comment: Sitecore.context.language is always en

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var lang = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("fr");
var item = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase.GetItem(this.ItemID, lang );
```